# Unable to get Dynamodb table values in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I have a DynamoDB table called "Users"
Where there is only one partition key called "UserID"

[image]

I have only two values in the table and would like to get all values from the value in the partition key.

[image]

I have tried a few different things to get it.

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1')
table = dynamodb.Table('Users')    
table.get_item(Key={"UserId":"blahblah"})
Output

    {'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'blah', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'server': 'Server', 'date': 'Sat, 15 Jul 2017 13:09:12 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0', 'content-length': '2', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': 'blah', 'x-amz-crc32': '2745614147'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

Also tried

```
client = boto3.client('dynamodb',"us-east-1")
client.get_item(TableName='Users', Key={"UserId":{"S":"blahblah"}})

{'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'blah', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'server': 'Server', 'date': 'Sat, 15 Jul 2017 13:13:19 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0', 'content-length': '2', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': 'blah', 'x-amz-crc32': '2745614147'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

As we can see there is some content length in there but I dont understand Y I can get them ??

Any ideas or hints?

Comment: The code seems correct. I guess you have some kind of permission error. Are you using a valid AWS keypair?

Comment: Yup.. I double checked that..

Comment: When i reproduce the problem I get the same error if I try to get an item that doesnt exist. But if the data exists I also get an `Item` entry in the json response that contains the data.

Comment: It would be awesome if u could share ur code... I still dont get any Item in the response data

Comment: Works fine for me with the 2nd variant of the code. Use the CLI to check things: aws dynamodb scan --table-name Users. It should return the item count and array of items.